# How to list prometheus alerts in a dashboard in grafana?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, grafana-alerts, prometheus-alertmanager

I have a stack where I create alerts in Prometheus. These alerts are listed under [Grafana > Alert > Alert Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGegW.png).

I wanted to create a dashboard where I could view the alerts in a simple way. Like normal and firing status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query alert in firing or pending status with metric `ALERTS`.

It will return metric of the following format:

```
ALERTS{alertname="Watchdog", alertstate="firing", severity="warning"} 1
```

But, as far as I know, you cannot query alerts in passive state.

If you really want all alerts, you could get them from rules with the request to `api/v1/rules?type=alert`, but you'll need JSON plugin for this.

Comment: Do you have any example and some dashboard that I can use?

Comment: @PabloMarques, sorry, it is not clear, what kind of example do you expect? Create Table panel with query `ALERTS`, and you'll see alerts. Or do you want [link to dashboard](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/11098-alerts/) in store?

Comment: I was looking for an example, but I racked my brain thinking and I managed to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Install Plugin [Json API](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-json-datasource/?tab=installation) in Grafana.
  "*`Versions above 1.3.3 had some issues.`*"
- Create [Data Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Cod.png) in Grafana .

[image: result]